# Use $group to sum the values for two different values of the same key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Say I have data that looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"jack",
    "net_worth":1000
}
```

And I want to do an aggregate that returns the average net worth of everyone named "john" or "jack" as a single number.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$group:
        {"_id":"$name",
         "average_worth":{$avg:"$net_worth"}
        }
    }    
])
```

This aggregation would return the average net worth for people in the collection with the same name. How would I average two (or more) specific names? I know I can do a `$match` to filter out everyone but Johns and Jacks, but I don't know how to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$match` combined with `$or`:

```
> db.ppl.insert({"name": "jack", "worth" : 240000});
> db.ppl.insert({"name": "john", "worth" : 14000});
> db.ppl.insert({"name": "bill", "worth" : 88000000});

> db.ppl.aggregate([ 
     { $match:{$or:[{name:"jack"},{name:"john"}]}}, 
     {$group : { "_id" : 1, "average_worth":{$avg:"$worth"} } }])
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "average_worth" : 127000
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Note that I had to come up with some bogus `_id` for the `$group`, because we need the same id for results from both jack and john.